# Android User Inter Action with phone

Tags: android

I want to know if a user silent or unsilent the phone. How to detect user interaction with phone volume if user unsilent the phone my function will trigger
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect whether the phone is in silent mode or not by using  [getRingerMode()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode%28%29) method in `AudioManager`.

```
AudioManager mAudio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (mAudio.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        // your phone is in Silent Mode
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        // your phone is in Vibrate Mode
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        // your phone is in Normal Mode
        break;
}
```

Apply your logic with this code to determine when the mode of the phone gets changed and call your function accordingly.

**EDIT :**  To detect change in the ringer mode, declare a **`RingerModeStateChangeReceiver`** which extends **`BroadcastReceiver`** and use this code inside `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` or `Service` that you want to process the broadcast:

```
      BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               //call your function here
          }
      };
      IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(
                      AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);
      registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it won't help me I need to catch the user action when he silent or un silent. I want to catch his action directly by his action.Is there any method to catch his un silent action.??? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION`. I have edited my answer as well. That should help you.

Comment: @Swayam I have a scenario where both my app and the user might change the ringer mode. My app already has a receiver listening to RINGER_MODE_CHANGED action and the app uses AudioManager to change the mode (eg: **audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE)**). Is there a way to differentiate between the change in ringer mode by user and by the AudioManager (app)?